# Response had HTTP status code 500, no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: java, jax-rs, internal-server-error

I have a simple java web service deployed(say /diagnosis). When i hit the URL(/diagnosis) i am getting the JSON output. When i try to hit the rest service(/diagnosis) through Angular JS i am getting:

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4201' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.**

My Java code is:

```
@GET
@Path("/DiagnosisSortProviderCost")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response DiagnosisSortProviderCost() throws Exception {

    // String path_name = "C:\\Users\\526761\\Desktop\\PioDel\\";
    JSONArray jsonArr = jsonread.json_extract_provider(path_name);

    System.out.println("--");
    System.out.println(jsonArr);

    Response response = Response.status(200).entity(jsonread.pro_DiagProvCost(jsonArr))
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();

    return response;
}
```

I added the code to resolve CORS Filter issue, i even replaced the * with IP and port. Yet i couldn't get the issue resolved.

Please help me!!!

Comment: Check your server logs for whatever messages that are getting logged when that 500 internal server failure happens.

Comment: If you go in debug can you verify that `response` really has that header?

Comment: _"I added the code to resolve CORS Filter issue"_ - Where's the filter you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
@Path("/DiagnosisSortProviderCost")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Because your mapping will never work. It only support GET method, in case of different http method like OPTIONS (for CORS), it will not serve.

All browser will send OPTIONS firstly to detect which method is allowed before sending actually request. If OPTIONS is not support or http method is not supported, browser will prevent it.

Change it to [@RequestMaping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) with method option:  The HTTP request methods to map to, narrowing the primary mapping: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, TRACE.

Comment: @ChrisPioline Why are you screaming dude?

Comment: ha haa..    I never thought people would take it as screaming..    I just simply typed that